# jQuery: passing $this with other parameters to function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parameters

How can i pass the `this` with other parameters to function? Tried the following without success:

```js
    function update_alt($this,my_param){
        this_alt=$(this).attr('alt');
        $(this).attr('alt',this_alt+my_param);
    }

//  $('.asd img').each(update_alt); // passing $this ok
    $('.asd img').each(update_alt(this,prompt('alt?',''))); // null
```

Comment: You are not even accessing `$this` inside the callback. What do you want it to refer to? And what do you want `this` to refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd reference your img variable as `item` or `element` because `this` is special keyword and it can be hard to track exactly what is being referred to when moving between functions.

With that in mind, these changes may solve your bug:

```
function update_alt(item, my_param) {
  var $item   = $(item);
  var new_alt = $item.attr('alt') + my_param;
  $item.attr('alt', new_alt);
}

$('.asd img').each(function(index, item) { 
  update_alt(item, prompt('alt?',''));
});
```

Comment: @Bigood you were very quick! Sorry I hadn't refreshed to load the it as I was typing.

Answer (score 1):

In `update_alt()`, you might rename all your `this` to `element`, for code clarity. Plus, you weren't using `$this` in your function.

Change it for this :

```
function update_alt(element,my_param){
    element_alt= $(element).attr('alt');
    $(element).attr('alt',element_alt+my_param);
}
```

Then, to use it, you should call it in another function, so `this` is referring to the current element:

```
$('.asd img').each(function(){
    update_alt(this,prompt('alt?',''));   //"this" has a meaning in this closure
});
```